# How can you interrogate the contents of a Content Pack using Apex and SOQL?

Tags: soql, content

It is possible to query for all the Content Packs in your Org using a query similar to:

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE FileType = 'PACK'
```

However I can't find a way to subsequently query for all related Content files. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any exposed object that will show you the relationship between the Content Pack ContentVersion and the member ContentVersion records.

As you have found, you can find the ContentVersion record based on the FileType being 'PACK'. You can also see the ContentVersion records that make up the pack. But there is currently no way to see the the connecting relationship.

> "You can't create, edit, or delete content packs via the API."
>    Source: [Online Docs - ContentDocument](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)

The following Idea includes exposing the relationship in the API:
 [Show Where Content is Used in Content Packs or Deliveries](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HuTDAA0).

> Users cannot delete Content that is part of some other Content Pack.  They are notified but it seems they have no way to see which Content Packs are in question.  Let's put this information on the Content's Detail Page, perhaps in a related list.  That way, users could notify Content Pack owners to remove or update the items from the packs.  **Let's make this function from the API and Reports too**.

Additional References:

- [Force.com Discussion Boards - SOQL ContentVersion and Content Packs](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/SOQL-ContentVersion-and-Content-Packs/td-p/471709)
- [CloudSpokes Challenge - Where is my Salesforce Content Being Used?](http://www.cloudspokes.com/challenges/1343)

Comment: Was the Cloudspokes challenge cancelled? I can't tell :)

Comment: @WesNolte, I couldn't tell either. Certainly seems like they ran into the same issue. I hadn't really seen ClodeSpokes before. Looks a bit like a StackExchange site with more in depth problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?:

> Select Title, ParentId, OwnerId, LastModifiedDate, Id, CreatedDate 
>   From ContentDocument

Comment: Unfortunately not. The Content Pack is a collection of Content files, and you can find the collections but it seems you cannot programmatically interrogate the constituent files :/