# Rest API download content packs

Tags: rest-api, contentversion, contentdocument

I'm trying to download [content versions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) through Rest API. I am not able to download content packs (FileType = 'PACK'). However, the same could be done through Salesforce web which downloads as a zip file. How can this be done through Rest API? The content document [api doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm) says that

> You can't create, edit, or delete content packs via the API.

But it means that you can query and retrieve the contents. The content size when queried is 0. How can I retrieve the data for content packs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [How can you interrogate the contents of a Content Pack using Apex and SOQL?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/13255/102) I don't believe this is currently possible via the APIs.

The content pack isn't actually stored in Salesforce. It is created as required from the pack ContentVersions. Hence the size of 0 on the actual pack.

If you could query via the API for which files make up the content pack then you could pull each one down independently. Consider voting for [Show Where Content is Used in Content Packs or Deliveries](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HuTDAA0) to achieve this.